# How to be sure that my data types are float64 in my equations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with index (Dates) and two columns (A and B). The DataFrame type, is float64 at these columns.

I am using for loop, to make some calculations. and i want to add the results x1 and x2 to a new columns, Alpha and Beta, Respectively.

I tried to use the following line to recognize the data type

```
print (df.dtypes)
```

to see the type of my data, after ...

```
df.at[Rw+1,'Alpha']=x1
```

My code is:

```
for Rw in range(25):    
        def adj(df):                
            R=float(df.iloc[Rw,1])
            V=float(df.iloc[Rw+1,1])

            if R>=V:
                x1=R-V   
            else:
                x2=(V-R)**3

            df.at[Rw+1,'Alpha']=x1      
            print (df.dtypes)
            df.at[Rw+1,'Beta']=x2    
        adj(df)
```

I get an Error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtypes'
```

I'm afraid that lines with .at[ _ ] in the loop, are not represents float64 types.

How can i be sure or how can i change to float64 or how can i add these "Alpha" and "Beta" to my DataFrame? ...i am using python27.

Comment: What's `df.dtypes` before the loop?  The error suggests the `df` has been changed from DataFrame to a float, not just `float64`.  A `np.float64` will have a `dtype` attribute, but not `dtypes`.

Comment: I'm not certain what your code is doing, but it's usually bad form to loop through a data frame.  Consider the following https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/#pandas-apply.  Additionally, if you're new to python and not being forced to use legacy python (2.7), then you should upgrade to 3.x; consider installing the Anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change lines:

```
df.at[Rw+1,'Alpha']=x1      
df.at[Rw+1,'Beta']=x2
```

to :

```
df.ix[Rw+1,'Alpha']=x1      
df.ix[Rw+1,'Beta']=x2
```